# Native method not found:

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

Help me please. This is my first code in NDK.
I make all how showed in this video [Using Native code (C,C++)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0vL7-_xuDM) but I get Native method not found:
C file name is "ndktest.c"

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

extern "C" jstring Java_com_checksound_visualisator_MainActivity_helloWorld(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello Urma");
}
```

My java class is

```
package com.checksound.visualisator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity...

public native String helloWorld();

static {
    System.loadLibrary("ndktest");
}
```

Comment: Could you share setup for ndk in `local.properties` and `build.gradle` file ?

Comment: Did the *.so file get generated during build?

Comment: mdtuyen Yes ndk.dir=E\:\\programms\\android\\android-ndk-r10e

Answer (score 0):

@Tsung-Ting,

You may want to check whether the C file is in the JNI folder.

Secondly,

In your build.gradle, try add:
model {

```
// The android{} block configure all android specific building options

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.checksound.visualisator"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel 22
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    ndk {
        moduleName = "native"
    }
}
```

}

Good luck!